# Facebook send application invite to random user in my Friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, invitation, facebook-app-requests

I want to send my Application invites to multiple random people in my friends list just as its done in majority of application. 
For Instance [image]

As soon as i Accept the application this pop up appears.What i cannot understand is how to get the ID's of these users ? On the Client Side ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <p>
      <input type="button"
        onclick="sendRequestToRecipients(); return false;"
        value="Send Request to Users Directly"
      />
      <input type="text" value="User ID" name="user_ids" />
      </p>
    <p>
    <input type="button"
      onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
      value="Send Request to Many Users with MFS"
    />
    </p>

    <script>
      FB.init({
        appId  : '423165827708510',
        frictionlessRequests: true,
      });

      function sendRequestToRecipients() {
        var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_ids,                        ///  How to Fill the ID's HERE ?
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to send to random users? 
That doesn't make any sense - surely you'd invite the people you think will like the game?!

Confusion aside, to answer your question, the 'to' parameter is either an array, or a comma seperated list of user IDs.

Here's an example of CSV, taken from [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/):

```
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request',
    to: '499802820,499802852'
  }, requestCallback);
}
```

Comment: -` FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
The Response has a list of ID's and Names  , Now how can i extract random ID's and pass it to the  sendRequestToRecipients()  
     });`

Comment: By randomising the results; finding out how to do this should take a few seconds with Google

Comment: I tried it but it returned some complicated  Fisher-Yates algorithm for randomising the response .

Comment: Does this not work?
//Randomize the order of the array:
`var myarray=[25, 8, "George", "John"]
myarray.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()}) //Array elements now scrambled`

Comment: FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
   
   var myarray=response ;
   myarray.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
   
   document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].html = response ;
   
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + myarray + '.');

Is giving me
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sort'

Comment: One more question . How do you Format  the Code here in Comments ? CTRL + k ?

Comment: If they're still in the Object structure, load the user IDs into an array and sort that instead

Comment: I am not sure how thats done ?

var myarray = eval ("(" + response + ")"); ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11657/discussion-between-adi-mathur-and-igy)